# How to delete multiple words separated by symbols such as class="hello" in vim?

Tags: vim

Let's say I want to delete `class="hello"` in the example below:

```
<div class="hello" id="test">
```

I know there's `diw` to delete the word the cursor is on top and I also know there's a command that would delete `class="hello"` in its entirety but I can't remember it nor do I  have words to make the right google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim allows you to operate on a "word" (colloquially: "small word") or a "WORD" (colloquially: "big word"). The two are described under `:help word`.

In your example:

- `class`, `=`, `"`, `hello`, and `"` are all "small words", covered by the `iw` text object,
- `class="hello"` is a single "big word", covered by the `iW` text object.

---

FWIW, both the "word" vs "WORD" notion *and* the `iW` text object are easily discoverable from a simple `:help iw`. No need for Google, here.